# Updating specific elements in C array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having trouble conceptualising how to go about some of my code.

My C program wishes to compare each individual element of an array of structs aka `arr_person[i].name` against a user's input to see if there's a match. (i.e. if the user types in "Billy" and "Billy" is also a string in `arr_person[].name` array)

```
for(i=0;i<num_of_lines;i++)
{
    if(strcmp(nameInput, arr_person[i].name)==0) {
        printf("Match at element %d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Then, a separate function finds reoccurring elements within `arr_person[i].name` by iterating through the array, and if the same name occurs twice, it will take the corresponding integer values of the same elemental positions and will add them up and store in new variable `newChange`. For example, if "Billy" occurs twice in the array, at `arr_person[0].name` and `arr_person[4].name`, and `arr_person[0].number = 15` and `arr_person[4].number = 10`, then I want to update the number such that it becomes 25.

```
for(i = 0; i < num_of_lines; i++) {
        for(j=0;j<num_of_lines;j++) {
            if(strcmp(arr_person[j].name, arr_person[i].name)==0) 
                *newNumber = arr_person[i].number + arr_person[j].number;
            }
        }
```

How do I go about this so that any elements in the array that **don't** reoccur are still kept the same?

If the user inputs "Rachel" and Rachel only appears once in the array, and her corresponding number is 85, I want to print

> Rachel 85

But if the user inputs "Billy" and Billy occurs twice, and he has the two numbers 10 and 15 as corresponding integers in another array, I want to print

> Billy 25

I've only been programming for a few months. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is supposed to happen with the matching entries? Should they be removed from the array? If you want to run that function multiple times you would add up to the sum each time if you keep them in the array.

Comment: From your description, it is not clear what you want the function to do. On the one hand (as suggested by the code) you want to find any repeated name in the array. On the other hand (as suggested by the details following the code), you want to find occurrences of a specific name provided as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the only thing you need to do is this:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0;i<num_of_lines;i++)
{
    if(strcmp(nameInput, arr_person[i].name)==0) 
        sum += arr_person[i].number;
}
```

I would structure it like this:

```
// Previous code from your post slightly modified to function
// returns -1 on no match and index otherwise
int match(struct person *arr_person, char *nameInput, int num_of_lines)
{
    for(int i=0;i<num_of_lines;i++) {
        if(strcmp(nameInput, arr_person[i].name)==0) 
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int sum(struct person *arr_person, char *nameInput, int num_of_lines)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<num_of_lines;i++) {
        if(strcmp(nameInput, arr_person[i].name)==0) 
            sum += arr_person[i].number;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() 
{
    // Insert code for declaration and initialization

    int index = match(arr_person, nameInput, num_of_lines);
    if(index >= 0) {
        printf("Match at element %d\n", index);
        printf("%s %d\n", nameInput, sum(arr_person, nameInput, num_of_lines));
    } else {
        printf("No match\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to update the arr_person.change array instead of returning sum? I need to access all of the values from the array at once to perform a further calculation on each of them. Would I create a new array for this?